# Why is ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot() returning R/?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I need to open dialog to select a file container, but the list of containers in new dialog is empty.  I see that the problem is that the ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot() is returning "R/". Does anyone know why?

```
ContainerSelectionDialog dialog = new ContainerSelectionDialog(getShell(),ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot(),false,"Select new file container");

if (dialog.open() == ContainerSelectionDialog.OK) 
    {
        Object[] result = dialog.getResult();
        if (result.length == 1) 
        {
            destinationDirectory.setText(((Path) result[0]).toString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: That is correct. This works testing here. Don't forget that your test will be running in the test Eclipse workspace not your main workspace. You will need to create projects and folders in that workspace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot()` returns an instance of  `IWorkspaceRoot` - the `toString()` method of this will return `R/`. This is correct.

```
IWorkspaceRoot root = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot();

// This will print 'R/' string representation of the workspace root
System.out.println(root);

IPath fullPath = root.getFullPath();

// This will print the file path to the workspace root
System.out.println(fullPath.toOSString());
```

When you test your plugin from within Eclipse a new workspace is created for the test run. You will need to create projects in that test workspace to see them in the selection dialog.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Now I understand.